# Running Mongo eval within Docker container returns random string?

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to run the following Docker mongo client with eval that gets all database names. However it returns a string like 6baed0a2a2b0aac93d56a02238132cb9726. What is this string? If I run mongo client on localhost it does return correct database names.

```
docker run --name NAME -d mongo --host SERVER --username USER --password PASS --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --eval \"printjson(db.getMongo().getDBNames())\" > availableMongoDatabases.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Returned string by `docker run` is the container id. It doesn't have nothing to do with application which executes inside the container.

Therefore, string like `6baed0a2a2b0aac93d56a02238132cb9726` what you talk about is different on each container and so, you'll get a different one each time you execute `docker run`. If you want to access the same container, don't execute `docker run` but `docker exec -ti [container_id] bash`

Comment: How can I run mongo on the same docker container I have already started? Instead of spawning another docker instance?